# Chart control data series

Tags: c#, winforms, graph, charts, microsoft-chart-controls

I have a chart control.I am plotting price along y axis and month-year along x axis.

I add series1 1st and then series2 to the same chart area.
Then I plot the points for series 1 and 2 using the below code

```
curveChart.Series.Add("Series1");
curveChart.Series["Series1"].XValueType = ChartValueType.DateTime;
curveChart.Series["Series1"].Points.DataBind(list1, "MonthYear", "PriceValue", null);
curveChart.Series["Series1"].ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Line;
curveChart.Series["Series1"].BorderWidth = 3;
curveChart.ChartAreas["0"].AxisX.Interval = 1;

curveChart.Series.Add("Series2");
curveChart.Series["Series2"].XValueType = ChartValueType.DateTime;
curveChart.Series["Series2"].Points.DataBind(list2, "MonthYear", "PriceValue", null);
curveChart.Series["Series2"].ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Line;
curveChart.Series["Series2"].BorderWidth = 3;
curveChart.ChartAreas["0"].AxisX.Interval = 1;
```

The problem I am facing is that list2 contains data only till Dec-2015 and list1 contains data till Dec-2016 but when the graph is plotted both the lines in the graph extend upto Dec-2016 though list2 doesnt have data till Dec-2016.How can I solve this?

Comment: What is happening now and what do you want to have happen when there are missing data points?

Comment: list2 doesnt contain data from Jan-2016 to Dec-2016 but list1 contains data till Dec-2016. As of now both the graphs are plotted until Dec-2016 though list2 doesnt contain that data only.I wish if the graph could be plotted only for available datapoints in list2

Comment: I tried using curveChart.DataManipulator.IsEmptyPointIgnored = true; and it still did not work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried to simulate your problem.  I added two data series one with 3 points, one with 2 points.  The chart rendered correctly.  This makes me think you are going to have to massage your data before you bind it.

[image]

```
curveChart.Series.Clear();
curveChart.Series.Add("Series1");
curveChart.Series["Series1"].XValueType = ChartValueType.DateTime;
curveChart.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(DateTime.Now, 12.00m);
curveChart.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(DateTime.Now.AddDays(1), 13m);
curveChart.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(DateTime.Now.AddDays(2), 8m);
curveChart.Series["Series1"].ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Line;
curveChart.Series["Series1"].BorderWidth = 3;
curveChart.ChartAreas["0"].AxisX.Interval = 1;

curveChart.Series.Add("Series2");
curveChart.Series["Series2"].XValueType = ChartValueType.DateTime;
curveChart.Series["Series2"].Points.AddXY(DateTime.Now, 5.00m);
curveChart.Series["Series2"].Points.AddXY(DateTime.Now.AddDays(1), 7m);          
curveChart.Series["Series2"].ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Line;
curveChart.Series["Series2"].BorderWidth = 3;
curveChart.ChartAreas["0"].AxisX.Interval = 1;
```